# creating handles in a for loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm creating a GUI with a large number of checkboxes

```
h.f = figure('units','pixels','position',[200,200,150,50],...
             'toolbar','none','menu','none');
for i=1:100
    num_data=round((100*(5*rand()))/100);    
end
h.t(i) = uicontrol('style','text','units','pixels',...
            'position',[30,820-15.*i,150,15],'string','za');

h.c.a(i) = uicontrol('style','checkbox','units','pixels',...
            'position',[150,820-15.*i,125,15],'string','1');

if num_data>1            
    h.c.b(i) = uicontrol('style','checkbox','units','pixels',...
            'position',[175,820-15.*i,25,15],'string','2');  

end
if num_data>2
    h.c.c(i) = uicontrol('style','checkbox','units','pixels',...
            'position',[200,820-15.*i,25,15],'string','3');

end
if num_data>3
    h.c.d(i) = uicontrol('style','checkbox','units','pixels',...
            'position',[225,820-15.*i,25,15],'string','4');

end
if num_data>4
    h.c.e(i) = uicontrol('style','checkbox','units','pixels',...
            'position',[250,820-15.*i,25,15],'string','5');

end



h.p = uicontrol('style','pushbutton','units','pixels',...
                'position',[40,5,70,20],'string','OK',...
                'callback',@p_call);
    % Pushbutton callback
    function p_call(varargin)
        vals=get(h.c, 'Value');
        checked = find([vals{:}]);
        if isempty(checked)
            checked = 'none';
            disp(checked)
        else
            for i=checked
            Data1=dlmread(strcat(files{i}, ' PYRO.txt'),2,0);
            plot(Data1(3:end,1),Data1(3:end,2))
            hold on
            end
        end
    hold off
```

The code is placing the checkboxes in the right place, but h is disappearing at the end of the for loop, and this is the error I'm getting.

```
??? Undefined variable "h" or class "h.c".

Error in ==> checkboxesGUI>p_call at 50
        vals=get(h.c, 'Value');

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

How do I make it so I can call back on h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `p_call` does not have access to the struct `h` where your handles are stored.  Your entire code is not posted, but it seems clear that `p_call` is not nested in the function that owns `h`.  Restructure your code so `p_call` has access to `h`, or pass `h` as an input argument every time it is called.

Also, a problem is that `h.c` is a struct, not a handle.  Your handles are in the subfields of `h.c` (i.e. `h.c.a`, `h.c.b`, etc.).  This is a bit messy, so I would suggest changing the code so you keep the checkbox handles in an array addressed via `h.c(i)` so your `get` and `find` lines will work.